# HSQLDB default_table_type not honoured in JDBC URL

Tags: jdbc, hsqldb

I'm using the connection URL `jdbc:hsqldb:file:/data/hsqldb/mydb;hsqldb.default_table_type=cached` with HSQLDB 2.1.  Issuing 'CREATE TABLE' does not persist anything (there's no `.data` file created).  Issuing 'CREATE CACHED TABLE' explicitly works correctly, however.  What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've fixed it: I wasn't issuing a SHUTDOWN command (I'm not exactly sure why my CREATE CACHED TABLE worked regardless, but never mind)

Answer (score 1):

The URL or connection property settings for the database are applied to new databases only. For an exsiting database, you should use `SET DATABASE DEFAULT TABLE TYPE CACHED`